# POST Data to another page of PHP for processing using Ajax using data not received

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Sender page

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST", // type of method
    url  : "1.php", // your page
    data : { PID : $PID, PQ : $ProductNeed }, // passing the values
    success: function(res) { }
});
```

---

Receiver Page

```
if (isset($_POST['PID'])) {
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "call herestoredProcedure('".$_SESSION['USERid'])."','".$_POST['PQ']."','".$_POST['PID']."')";
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

_POST Not Receiving data of PID, PQ Indexer. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($_POST)`;

Comment: If *"_POST Not Receiving data of PID, PQ"* , then you should check the `$PID` and  `$ProductNeed` variables at the client side code. what does `console.log($PID)` and `console.log($ProductNeed)` show in your browser ?

Comment: how do i print because it is just send data to server for insert data in database

Comment: Time to use the debugging tools you have available to you.  In your browser's debugger, place a breakpoint just before the AJAX call.  Do the variables have the values you expect them to have?  When the AJAX call is made, observe it in the browser's network debugging panel.  Does the request have the values you expect?  What is the server's response?  In your server-side code, what happens when you `print_r($_POST)` or `print_r($result)` or `echo mysqli_error($conn)` and observe the output in your browser's network debugger?  Does it contain what you expect?

Comment: AJAX Connected and variables data is accurate problem is when isset() function call to check values are there in 1.php then it returns false

Comment: @UmerIbrahim: If `isset()` returns `false` then the value is not set.  It sounds like you're doing more assuming than debugging.  Can you provide the information you're looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked this one and it's working perfectly if you still got the problem try this I think your problem in path or something in my code all the files in same folder so check for that.

callto1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

</div>

<script>
var $PID = 1;
var $ProductNeed=2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url : "1.php", // your page
    type : "POST", // type of method
    data : { PID : $PID, PQ : $ProductNeed }, // passing the values
    success: function(res) {
        alert(res);
     }
});
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

1.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['PID']) && isset($_POST['PQ'])){
    echo "came";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks the problem is now solved document.ready not used before

Comment: Your welcome next time post the whole code and name the files to it's easy for us to understand  and give perfect answer to you... happy coding 

Comment: Ok i'll Remember

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in URL parameter. It's not "1 .php" but "1.php". Also I do not advise you to name php files only by numbers.

Comment: when i call 1.php without using posted values direct putting values in call storeprocedure all working properly but when i use posted values it return isset false